# How to automatically generate XHTML heading levels using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

For example, how would I turn this:

```
<chapter name="Chapter 1">
  <chapter name="Chapter 1.1">
    <chapter name="Chapter 1.1.1">
      <chapter name="Chapter 1.1.1.1"/>
    </chapter>
    <chapter name="Chapter 1.1.2"/>
  </chapter>
  <chapter name="Chapter 1.2"/>
</chapter>
```

into this:

```
<h1>Chapter 1</h1>
<h2>Chapter 1.1</h2>
<h3>Chapter 1.1.1</h3>
<h4>Chapter 1.1.1.1</h4>
<h3>Chapter 1.1.2</h3>
<h2>Chapter 1.2</h2>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm very new to XSLT. I have tried a few things, but always end up with what I would consider to be 'hard coded' solutions. I thought I would pose the question in it's pure form without polluting it with my (probably wrong) ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be several possibilities how to do it. It depends what signalize the level of heading (number in `@name` attribute? the depth of `chapter` element?).

I suppose it is the depth of `chapter` element. So for input xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<chapter name="Chapter 1">
    <chapter name="Chapter 1.1">
        <chapter name="Chapter 1.1.1">
            <chapter name="Chapter 1.1.1.1"/>
        </chapter>
        <chapter name="Chapter 1.1.2"/>
    </chapter>
    <chapter name="Chapter 1.2"/>
</chapter>
```

you could utilize template with parameter increasing in consecutive calling `apply-templates`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>xxx</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="chapter" />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="chapter">
        <xsl:param name="level" select="1" />

        <xsl:element name="h{$level}">
            <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
        </xsl:element>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="chapter">
            <!-- Increase level of heading -->
            <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level+1" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which produces following output

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>xxx</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Chapter 1</h1>
        <h2>Chapter 1.1</h2>
        <h3>Chapter 1.1.1</h3>
        <h4>Chapter 1.1.1.1</h4>
        <h3>Chapter 1.1.2</h3>
        <h2>Chapter 1.2</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

Edit: another idea could be count the number of "parent" chapter element like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>xxx</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//chapter" />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="chapter">
        <xsl:variable name="level" select="count(ancestor-or-self::chapter)" />
        <xsl:element name="h{$level}">
            <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Counting the number of parents is an elegant solution. Thanks.